# How to remove quotes from the value of a variable in rust

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I need to remove the quotes from the value of the variable, so that a variable of a different type is obtained.
From this:

```
let mut first_variable = "[67, 43, 26, 72]";
```

Into this:

```
let mut second_variable = [67, 43, 26, 72];
```

This should be executed while the program is running.

Comment: So you want to be able to take a string say "[1, 2, 3]" and turn it into a vec![1, 2, 3] ? Is this supposed to be during compile-time or when you run the program?

Comment: Deserialization is tough, you might want `serde` crate and some popular data exchange format like JSON or YAML

Comment: The quotes aren't part of the *value*; they're part of the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `serde-json` crate:

```
use serde_json; // 1.0.82

let k:[u32; 4] = serde_json::from_str("[67, 43, 26, 72]").unwrap();
```

Or if you want it to work regardless of length:

```
let k:Vec<u32> = serde_json::from_str("[67, 43, 26, 72]").unwrap();
```

Of course replace `u32` with whatever numeric type you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

I used a display code where
'let x = "{}", some_string;'
as in

```
writeln!(file, "{}", buffer.trim();
```